# Listen to DTMF tones during Sip/VoIP or regular calls

Tags: java, android, sip, voip, dtmf

i've read some articles about DTMF in Android. I guess that it's not possible to make an automatic phone call streaming a .wav file (or other format) and detect the input of the other person (receiver of the call).

I'm want to make an app that calls me/or someone else and is waiting for input to do some action.
Is this scenario possible with VoIP in Android? Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a cloud based telephony service like [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/home.jsp) and [Prophecy](http://evolution.voxeo.com/) to achieve this requirement.  These services allow you to make outbound calls and listen for either DTMF or voice input.  They also stream .wav file for the person on the phone to listen to.  You can trigger these calls from any application by just making an HTTP request to the services API, so it could be an Android app that initiates the call.  This solution is independent of the phone device (any mobile, VoIP phone, or land line) and it works on VoIP as well as PSTN.